# Delete JSON data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to remove a piece of a data from a JSON array. For example, I have this array;

```
var users = [];
io.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.on('nickname', function(nick){
      socket.nick = nick;
       users.push({
         user:socket.nick,
         userid:socket.id,
         socket:socket
       });
    });
```

I am trying to delete in users this way;

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    delete users[{
        user,
        userid,
        socket
    }];
   });
 });
```

How can I do that?

Comment: are you trying to delete a specific user, or the whole array?

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole users array or only a specific object in it?

Comment: Each connected user has its own nickname and id on that page.Disconnected user will be deleted in users array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using lodash methods to achieve what you are trying to: -

```
var _ = require('lodash');
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        _.pullAllWith(users, [{
             user:socket.nick,
             userid:socket.id,
             socket:socket
             }], _.isEqual)
       });
     });
```

see if this works..

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values of each of the properties of each user object, you could pass the values into a function and loop through the the users array to find a matching object and then splice it from the array (updated answer to pass in object to function):

```js
var users = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  users.push({
    user: i,
    userId: i,
    socket: i
  });
}

/**
 * Loop through the users array to find matching 
 * object to remove
 **/
var deleteUser = function(userToDelete) {
  for (var userObj in users) {
    var userObject = users[userObj];
    if (typeof userObject === "object" &&
      userObject.user === userToDelete.user &&
      userObject.userId === userToDelete.userId &&
      userObject.socket === userToDelete.socket) {
      users.splice(userObj, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(users);
};

deleteUser({
  user: 2,
  userId: 2,
  socket: 2
});
```

Comment: Each connected user has its own nickname and id on that page.Disconnected user will be deleted in users array.İts not a static  like 1 or 2 .

Comment: No, I know it's not a static. I just did the "i" count to have an example users array for you to see.